# Появляется ошибка TypeError: require.context is not a function при запуске тестов Jest

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|ts)$': 'ts-jest',
    },

    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    ],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],

};
```

plugins из  webpack.config.js

````
plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin('.temp/css-modules'),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {exclude: ['keycloak.json']}),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin(watchIgnorePaths),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].css',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isProduction ? 'production' : 'development'),
            'process.env.TEST_MODE': isTestMode,
            __DEV__: JSON.stringify(!isProduction),
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            favicon: 'src/assets/favicon.ico',
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
            template: PATHS.htmlTemplate,
            chunks: ['vendor', 'portal', 'styles'],
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
            },
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
            chunksSortMode: 'none',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(filesToCopy),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /ru/),
    ],```
````